# How can I calculate the row variance for large matrices?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a pretty large sparse matrix in R:

```
> dim(matrix)
[1] 60675 36807
```

Now, I wanted to calculate the row variance for this matrix using like this:

```
apply(matrix,1,var)
Error in asMethod(object) : 
    Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 102
```

I suppose my matrix is too large for this to work.
My solution was to use multiple cores for this issue like this:

```
mclapply(Matrix::t(matrix), var, mc.cores=16)
Error in asMethod(object) : 
    Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 102
```

But as you can see, I get the same error again.
Do you have any suggestions on how to handle this problem? Maybe subset the matrix and then calculate the variance?

Comment: Can you look into [this article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/09/avoid-apply-function-in-large-datasets/)? I think this mightl address your issue...

Comment: Can you tell us `class(matrix)` ?

Comment: I might work on this some more for fun if (1) you need it to be much faster than my current solution and (2) you give us a little bit more context/[mcve] (degree of sparsity/sparsity pattern, speed requirements ...)

Comment: I have RNAseq expression matrix data, where I want to filter out low variance genes (rows).

Comment: I cannot really tell you the sparsity degree (again cannot calculate it due to size issues), but there are ~42k rows with 0 rowSums. I had also thought about removing them first, that would decrease the size of this matrix.

Comment: what is `class(matrix)`?

Comment: the class is:
`
[1] "dgCMatrix"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Matrix"
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**sparseMatrixStats**](https://bioconductor.org/packages/sparseMatrixStats/) package on Bioconductor implements the [**matrixStats**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=matrixStats) API for [**Matrix**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Matrix) objects;

```r
# BiocManager::install("sparseMatrixStats")
library(sparseMatrixStats)

mat <- matrix(0, nrow=10, ncol=6)
mat[sample(seq_len(60), 4)] <- 1:4
sparse_mat <- as(mat, "dgCMatrix")
class(sparse_mat)
#> [1] "dgCMatrix"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "Matrix"

rowVars(sparse_mat)
#> [1] 0.0000000 0.1666667 1.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> [8] 0.0000000 2.8000000 0.0000000
```

Comment: This takes 0.006 seconds on my machine (compare with 22 seconds parallelized for my solution!)

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```r
library(Matrix)
d <- Matrix(0, nrow=60675, ncol=36087)
d[5,5] <- 1
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```r
library(matrixStats)
v <- rowVars(d)
```

> Error in rowVars(d) : Argument 'x' must be a matrix or a vector.

But we can do it by brute force:

```r
v <- numeric(nrow(d))
for (i in seq(nrow(d))) {if (i %% 250 == 0) cat("."); v[i] <- var(d[i,]) }
```

This is slow (about 60 seconds on an old-ish MacOS desktop) but works. Parallelizing helps:

```r
library(parallel)
f <- function(i) var(d[i,])
v <- unlist(mclapply(seq(nrow(d)), f, mc.cores = 4))
```

(22 seconds elapsed).

Comment: not thought this through but would it be feasible to just calculate on the rows which have nonzeros, along the lies of `idx <- unique(d@i)` ;  and then loop through idx and calculate  `var(d@x[d@i == i])` (need care on the `i` index)

Comment: Sure, something like that should work.  Whether it's worth it depends on your sparsity pattern: what fraction of rows are empty?

Comment: Might also depend on storage mode -- this would be a little be easier if the sparse matrix was row-oriented rather than column-oriented, but I think most `Matrix` classes are column-oriented ...

Comment: TBH I don't know whether `d[i,]` converts to a non-sparse matrix, or whether one could/should define `var` to operate on sparse structures  -- you could certainly do something better by working harder/thinking more.  I was just trying to come up with something that worked at all.

Comment: yup ... (and my though above would ignore the zeros in the var calc)

Comment: This works, but much slower for me than for you and I used 16 cores on a computing cluster :/